# Gave up waiting for root device. Fresh Install Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS

Tags: boot, partitioning, system-installation, live-usb, boot-partition

I really hope somebody can help me. I have a Lenovo Y580 with a 16GB msata and a 1TB HDD. My goal is to mount the root filesystem on the msata drive (os, apps, and boot) for good load times and mount the /home directory to my 1TB HDD for (music, downloads, pictures etc). I have tried the past week to figure it out but whenever I do a fresh install (wipe all partitions within both drives and install the OS onto the 16GB msata) and it gets to the point where ubuntu tells me to restart I get the following after restarting:

```
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
  -Boot args (cat/proc/cmdline)
   -Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
   -Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
  -Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
ALERT!  /dev/disk/by-uuid/e0d321d5-c4ee-42e1-aa38-fbcf2a671775 does not exist.
Dropping to a shell!

BusyBox v1.21.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-1ubuntu1) built-in shell (ash)
Enter 'help' for a list of built-in commands.

(initramfs)
```

I have tried reinstalling along with many different partitioning schemes. Have also disable UEFI and secureboot, even tried turning off AHCI in bios with no avail. The LiveUsb is the only way I can use Ubuntu as of right now. Please help and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem and tried this.
When computer comes on, go to the option which usually works for me it was the first on the grub menu(Ubuntu 14.04) and press 'e'. This takes you to a shell script, use the up, down, left and right keys to navigate. Remove the line beginning with the if statement right up to the fi (the end of the if statement).

To delete go to the beginning of the line and press the 'delete button'.
Go to the line on linux and where you see the `root=ro`, remove the `ro` and replace with the name of the ubuntu partition in my case it was `/dev/sda3`
so something like this:

```
root=UUID=<long number> ro becomes root=/dev/sda3 ro.
```

This solution for now is temporary (currently looking for a permanent solution) so it has to be done every time you shut down.

PS: If you don't know how to get the name of the Ubuntu partition go to this link: [bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net](http://bootinfoscript.sourceforge.net) and do what it says on there.
Hope this helps.
Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

I really do appreciate your answer, but it did not work in my case. But, I did try another separate usb. Used Unetbootin to make Ubuntu 14.04.3LTS Live USB. Booted with live USB. Once booted I used gparted to delete and format all partitions. I formatted my msata to a ext3 partition instead of ext4. Mounted the msata as `/` and I formatted my hdd as `/home` as ext4, I also put an 8GB swap on my HDD. Rebooted..... WORKS GREAT!!! For some reason using the root file system as ext4 format did not work on my computer, when I changed it to ext3 it worked great. Also verified that my `/home` directory is my 1TB HDD and it is. Hopefully this can be cleared up as to why ext4 did not work as a root fs in my case.

Comment: I tried to verify that the ext4 was the problem so I reinstalled and also did the same steps above but used ext4 on my root fs and it worked. Maybe I had a faulty usb the entire time??